# Unique constraint error due to schema.sql and hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm making a spring boot application where I'm first creating a table in DB and loading some initial data into it using [schema.sql and data.sql method](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql).

Below is schema.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
);
```

Below is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Double salary;

    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;

    public Employee(String name, Double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.lastUpdate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

}
```

When I'm performing a `POST` operation with below json payload, I'm getting error:
`Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID) [1, 'RAGHU', 250.1, TIMESTAMP '2022-04-23 00:00:00']";`

Json payload of POST request:

```
{
    
    "name": "Adam",
    "salary": 257.1,
    "last_update": "2022-04-22T18:30:00.000+00:00"
}
```

Application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=abc123
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

It seems to me hibernate is conflicting with my initial data load. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the GenerationType to `IDENTITY`. I think Hibernate at the moment is using a sequence starting from 1.

The mapping will look like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

You can enable SQL logging to verify that's actually running the correct queries:

```
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
```